# p:selectCheckboxMenu conflicts label and f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use `<p:selectCheckBoxMenu>` and a `<f:selectItems>` inside that.

As you know, `label` attribute for `<p:selectCheckBoxMenu>` is mandatory but when I want to use `<f:selectItems>`'s `itemLabel` attribute, it wants to get `itemLabel` for `<p:selectCheckBoxMenu>`'s label too.

My code :

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="Menu"
                      value="#{Controller.myList}"
                      label="Choose Item"
                      filter="true"
                      filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                      style="width:220px;"
                      panelStyle="width:300px">

    <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.AllItemsList}" var="p" itemValue="#{p.id}" />
    <f:converter converterId="myConverter" />
    <f:ajax event="change" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

My error :

> Validation Error : value Choose Item is not valid !

Comment: Try to use the property `converter` in the `p:selectCheckboxMenu` instead of using `f:converter`

Comment: @Pellizon : thanks but it didn't resolve the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

`<p:selectCheckboxMenu` expects to receive selected options of the same value you defined in `value` property.

So, if the value of the `<p:selectCheckboxMenu` is a `List<ObjectXY>`, the `itemValue` of `<f:selectItems>` must be an `ObjectXY`

You got close, but the problem is that you defined the  `itemValue` of the  `<f:selectItems>` as `#{p.id}`, when your component is expecting an object of type ObjectXY, not an id.

Here's what you should change:

```
 <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.AllItemsList}" var="p" itemValue="#{p}" itemLabel="#{p.id}" />
```

Comment: @Pelizon : No sorry. when i put the object it self in item value (itemValue = #{p}) it simply returns its String to the converter, not the object. I think its a bug of primefaces. because the only problem of my code is that primefaces returns label of components as the first item of it's members. anyway thanks :)